# Uncaught Error: Class 'Monolog\Logger' not found

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, php7, composer

I use PHP 7.0 on Apache 2.4.20 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I have followed [this guide](http://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/resumable-file-upload-part-2) to have upload functionality and would like to know what I can do to fix the following error that I receive:

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Monolog\Logger' not found in
>   /var/www/vendor/dilab/resumable.php/src/Resumable.php:49\nStack
>   trace:\n#0 /var/www/upload.php(11):
>   Dilab\Resumable->__construct(Object(Dilab\Network\SimpleRequest),
>   Object(Dilab\Network\SimpleResponse))\n#1 {main}\n thrown in
>   /var/www/vendor/dilab/resumable.php/src/Resumable.php on line 49

Can someone help me overcome this error on my server?

**Edit 1**: Composer doesn't download any dependency named "Monolog" or "Logger", so why is that happening? (note that this might be a Composer question and not a PHP question after all...)

Comment: Looks to me like `'Monolog\Logger' not found in /var/www/vendor/dilab/resumable.php/src/Resumable.php:49`, whats your question?

Comment: @MattClark Why downvote? The question is clear: How can I fix that error?

Comment: Did you fix the problem?

Comment: @mortezamalvandi Not yet..... No-one has helped me.

Comment: Did you by any chance miss the following line at the top? include 'vendor/autoload.php';

Comment: @Rein No, the problem was the one that was posted on the solution at last...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install Monolog as well.
Go to your project directory and execute:

```
composer require monolog/monolog
composer require php-console/php-console
```

Then edit your update.php and insert below use Dilab\Resumable;

```
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\PHPConsoleHandler;
```

That should do the trick.